# Set up Webpack and Babel to transpile / polyfill older code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack

I have an entire legacy AngularJS 1.x application that used to run through gulp and babel. We are transitioning to the newer Angular 2+ but I'm running into an issue trying to get Webpack to actually find and compile the legacy files. I've tried following instructions which are all almost identical like this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_QACBSqRBE

But the webpack config simply doesn't do anything to the existing files. Is there a way to grab a WHOLE FOLDER of older components, that DO NOT have any imports or exports? I feel like entry is supposed to follow the import dependency path but that just doesn't exist for older AngularJS 1.x projects.

Errors are NOT being thrown during the build it just...doesn't transpile or polyfill.

example of what that section of the config looks like:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

We did this recently. We created "dummy" entry point files to avoid having to change all of our AngularJS files to have require/import statements.

**./entry-points/feature1.ts**

```
export const importAll = (r: any): void => {
  r.keys().forEach(r);
};
importAll(require.context('./app/feature1', true, /module\.js$/));
importAll(require.context('./app/feature1', true, /(^(?!.*(spec|module)\.js).*\.js)$/));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
entry: {
  'feature1': './entry-points/feature1.ts'
}
```

[More detail here](https://brian.olore.net/wp/2018/01/build-angularjs-without-editing-thousands-of-files-journey-webpack-part-7/)